# 1048 Column value cannot be null

Tags: php, database, forms

I am stuck, I cannot fix this error that I am getting, and I think it may be that my database options are messed up

Here's where the data is put into a form

```
 <form name = "quoted" method="post" onsubmit="get_action(this);">
 <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
 <textarea class = "actual_quote" name = "actual_quote" required="required" placeholder = "Write the question here!"></textarea><br><br><br>
 <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
     <h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="Inspirational" id = "inspirational.php" checked="checked" />    <span>Inspirational</span></label><br>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="Funny" id = "funny.php" /> <span>Funny</span>    </label><br>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="OutofContext" id = "outofcontext.php"/>    <span>OutofContext</span></label>
 </div>
 <input id = "submit1" name="submit1"s type="submit"><br>
 </form>
```

and here's the php to put that into the database

```
     <?php
     $db_name = 'submissions';
     $db_user = 'root';
     $db_pass = '';
     $db_host = 'localhost';
     try {
     $db = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost;dbname=submissions', $db_user, $db_pass);
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
     }
     $actual_quote = (isset($_POST['actual_quote']) ? $_POST['actual_quote'] : null);
     $poster = (isset($_POST['poster']) ? $_POST['poster'] : null);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO data (actual_quote, poster) VALUES ( :actual_quote, :poster)";
     $query = $db->prepare($sql);
     $query->execute(array(':actual_quote'=>$actual_quote, ':poster'=>$poster));
?>
```

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'actual_quote' cannot be null' in C:\wamp\www\Quotr\webweb2.php on line 113 ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'actual_quote' cannot be null in C:\wamp\www\Quotr\webweb2.php on line 113 Call Stack
>   Time Memory Function Location
>   1 0.0015 257160 {main}( ) ..\webweb2.php:0 2 0.0206 267672 execute ( ) ..\webweb2.php:113

When I do click null in the database, and I click the submit button on the form the error goes away and data shows up in the database, but there is no values, there's nothing there

can someone tell me whats wrong and how to fix this, if it's in the code, I personally think there's an issue with the database, here's some pictures of that.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjkYn.png
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNlrM.png

(ignore the first 3 on the last picture, the last one is where I am at)

Comment: Sidenote: Get rid of the `s` after the `"` in `name="submit1"s`

Comment: You are setting  $actual_quote as null when $_POST['actual_quote'] is not set... yet on the database side you have set this field to not allow NULL. Either allow NULL on database, or send empty string (two single quotes) when $_POST['actual_quote'] is not set. Now... why $_POST['actual_quote'] is not set ... that is a different problem.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is wrong with the database. It is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.

When the database gives you those errors, it's telling you that you are trying to input "nothing" (null) into a column that doesn't allow it. You are sending nothing because if `$_POST['actual_quote']` isn't set, it's null. Either get rid of that action if it isn't set or allow null in the database.

Also: get rid of the `s` after the `"` in `name="submit1"s`.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting $actual_quote as null when $_POST['actual_quote'] is not set... yet on the database side you have set this field to not allow NULL. Either allow NULL on database, or send empty string (two single quotes) when $_POST['actual_quote'] is not set (as shown below).

```
$actual_quote = (isset($_POST['actual_quote']) ? $_POST['actual_quote'] : '');
```

Comment: so I did this but the database is logging when I click submit but the values are blank?

Comment: Are you getting the poster and not the actual_quote? or you are not getting either of poster and actual_quote? You have to now make sure your $poster and $actual_quote holds any value or not, before passing them to database. Seems that isset() on both is failing, hence empty values.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. The 'field name' in view page and the column name of database was indifferent. My problem was:

```
"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'MoneyMethod' cannot be null".
```

My view page input tag:

```
{!! Form::select("MoneyMethod", $MoneymethodInfo, null,["class"=>"form-control MoneyMethod required","id"=>"MoneyMethod"]) !!},
```

notice the spelling of 'MoneyMethod' in my database table `$table->string('MoneyMethod', 100);` the spelling of money method is same as view page but in my controller

```
$riskfund->Moneymethod  = Input::get('Moneymethod');
```

look carefully the spelling of 'Moneymethod' differs from view page and database table column. After correcting the spelling, it is working now.

So, check the spelling of 'field name' and 'column name of database table' in form, controller, model and database table. It may solve your problem.